# How would you format multiple properties when using Property Initialization? (.Net)

Tags: .net, formatting, coding-style, convention

For example:

```
root.Nodes.Add(new TNode() { Foo1 = bar1, Foo2 = bar2, Foo3 = bar3 });
```

or:

```
root.Nodes.Add(new TNode() { Foo1 = bar1, 
                             Foo2 = bar2, 
                             Foo3 = bar3 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it both ways.. IMO it depends on the complexity of the initialization.

If it is simple 2 or 3 properties I will initialize on one line generally, but if i'm setting up an object with values for insertion into a database or something that has alot of properties i'll break it out like your second example.

```
Income income = new Income
{
    Initials = something,
    CheckNumber = something,
    CheckDate = something,
    BranchNumber = something
};
```

or

```
return new Report.ReportData { ReportName = something, Formulas = something};
```

Answer (score 1):

Both notations are fine. I would simply suggest to use the first (1-line) notation whenever your line stay within 100 characters, and switch to the second (multi-line) notation whenever the expression is longer.

Answer (score 0):

For longer stuff I do it this way:

```
root.Nodes.Add(new TNode() {
    Foo1 = bar1, 
    Foo2 = bar2, 
    Foo3 = bar3
});
```